# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef') using react-chartjs2

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-chartjs-2

I'm encountering a Type Error in my React app when trying to render a Line chart using the **`react-chartjs-2`** and **`chart.js`** libraries. Here's the relevant code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import {
  Chart as Chart JS, 
  Line Element,
  Category Scale,
  Point Element,
  Linear Scale
} from 'chart.js';

Chart JS. register({
  Line Element,
  Category Scale,
  Linear Scale,
  Point Element
});

function App() {
  const data = {
    labels: ['Mon' ,'Tue', 'Wed'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Some stuff',
      data: [23,65,12],
      background Color: 'aqua',
      border Color: 'black',
      point Border Color: 'aqua',
      fill: true,
      tension: 0.4
    }]
  }

  const options = {
    plugins: {
      legend: true
    },
    scales: {
      y: {
        min: 3,
        max: 6
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div class Name='App'>Hello there
    <Line
      data={data}
      options={options}
    ></Line>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Error message:

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
printWarning @ react.development.js:209
error @ react.development.js:183
resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1592
useRef @ react.development.js:1629
ChartComponent @ chart.tsx:35
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateForwardRef @ react-dom.development.js:19226
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21636
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 16 more frames
Show less
react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
printWarning @ react.development.js:209
error @ react.development.js:183
resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1592
useRef @ react.development.js:1629
ChartComponent @ chart.tsx:35
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateForwardRef @ react-dom.development.js:19226
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21636
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 19 more frames
Show less
react.development.js:1630 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
    at useRef (react.development.js:1630:1)
    at ChartComponent (chart.tsx:35:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
useRef @ react.development.js:1630
ChartComponent @ chart.tsx:35
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateForwardRef @ react-dom.development.js:19226
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21636
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 16 more frames
Show less
react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
printWarning @ react.development.js:209
error @ react.development.js:183
resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1592
useRef @ react.development.js:1629
ChartComponent @ chart.tsx:35
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateForwardRef @ react-dom.development.js:19226
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21636
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 17 more frames
Show less
react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
printWarning @ react.development.js:209
error @ react.development.js:183
resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1592
useRef @ react.development.js:1629
ChartComponent @ chart.tsx:35
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateForwardRef @ react-dom.development.js:19226
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21636
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 20 more frames
Show less
react.development.js:1630 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
    at useRef (react.development.js:1630:1)
    at ChartComponent (chart.tsx:35:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
useRef @ react.development.js:1630
ChartComponent @ chart.tsx:35
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
updateForwardRef @ react-dom.development.js:19226
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21636
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 17 more frames
Show less
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(ChartComponent)> component:

    at ChartComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:58959:5)
    at div
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18687
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18720
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13923
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13944
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23391
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25892
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25809
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Show 15 more frames
Show less
react.development.js:1630 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
    at useRef (react.development.js:1630:1)
    at ChartComponent (chart.tsx:35:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
```

I've looked through the documentation and other resources, but I can't seem to find a solution to this issue. Can anyone help me understand what's causing this error and how to fix it?

Additional context:

- React version: 17.0.2
- react-chartjs-2 version: 4.3.0
- chart.

Comment: The error means that `React` is null in your system for some reason, e.g. `React` is null when trying to read `React.useRef` in the `ChartComponent` ([chart.tsx:35](https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/blob/master/src/chart.tsx#L35)). Are you sure you have the `react` dependency correctly installed? From your project root, what is the output of running `npm list react`?